# Why doesn't a XML attribute have a "parent" in .NET?

Tags: .net, xml

So, I'm writing a simple function to remove a XML node from a XML document. The easiest way to achieve this, as far as I can tell, is to:

1. Get a reference to the node that will be removed (`ChildNode`)
2. Get a reference to the node's parent using the `ChildNode.ParentNode` property (`ParentNode`)
3. Call the `ParentNode.RemoveChild(ChildNode)` method

Now, this works great if the child node is a `XmlElement`, but what if the child node was a XML *attribute*? According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.parentnode.aspx) for `XmlNode.ParentNode`, the property would return `nothing`, because "*[attributes] do not have parents.*"

Attributes most definitely do have "parents," do they not? An attribute must be assigned to a XML element, so the XML element would be the attribute's parent, in my mind.

Can someone clear up my misunderstanding, or clarify why the .NET Framework does not see attributes as having parents?

Comment: The XML standard can be somewhat fatuous about this sort of detail. The .NET implementation just matches the standard, which considers 'parent' and 'ancestor' to be distinct concepts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`XmlAttribute.OwnerElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.ownerelement.aspx) to get the owner of an attribute.

Your procedure will have to be modified to something like this:

1. Get a reference to the node that will be removed (`ChildNode`).
2. If the type of the node is `XmlAttribute` downcast to that type (`AttributeNode`) and get a reference to the node's parent using the `AttributeNode.OwnerElement` property (`ParentNode`). If not go to step 4.
3. Call the `ParentNode.Attributes.Remove(AttributeNode)` method. Skip remaining steps.
4. Get a reference to the node's parent using the `ChildNode.ParentNode` property (`ParentNode`).
5. Call the `ParentNode.RemoveChild(ChildNode)` method.

So basically you have to give attributes special treatment reflecting the fact that they are not really part of a parent-child hierarchy but rather - well, attributes - of an XML element.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Hard choice between these two answers, but I'll accept this one since it was earlier, and included the tip to use `XmlAttribute.OwnerElement`. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

A good question, and one where the answer lies in the specification, rather than with Microsoft (for once, some might say...).

[Over at the W3C](http://www.w3.org/XML/Core/), we can find [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/), which gets to overrule what any one of us might feel is intuitively obvious. In it, I find the word **parent** only **once**, [in this context](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-well-formed):

> [Definition: As a consequence of this, for each non-root element C in
>   the document, there is one other element P in the document such that C
>   is in the content of P, but is not in the content of any other element
>   that is in the content of P. P is referred to as the parent of C, and
>   C as a child of P.]

Note that here "element" refers only to actual *elements*; and "content" refers only to child *elements*. The `XmlNode` concept is an **abstraction** (which does *not* appear in the specification) which is part of the library, not the standard.

I suppose MS *could* have made the implementation of `ParentNode` for attributes return the owning element, but then would you want `ChildNodes` for an element to include the attributes? That seems less desirable.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. However, I would have to disagree on that last point: "Would you want `ChildNodes` to include attributes?" Well, for the sake of consistency, I would like to see that, yes. If an XML attribute is-a `Node`, then it would logically follow that `ChildNodes` would return attributes as well as elements.